# Prevent duplicate insert without session

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

im working on sharepoint 2010 (using visual webpart) is there any way to prevent duplicate

insert in a list when page is refreshed using F5, without using session

thx

Answer (score 0):

The sharepoint "way" is usually to redirect to the list view page after you have inserted a new item:

So the web part posts to some page, with a Source parameter:

```
http://somesite/Lists/TestList/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite%2FLists%2FTestList%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder=&...
```

Then after the save event, redirect

```
SPUtility.Redirect(base.ListEditPageLayoutsRelativeUrl, SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, this.Context);
```

Comment: thx, but in my webpart i dont give users the ability to see the list view page i just show information message like (thx for your ...)

Comment: you should be able to redirect to the same page your web part is on

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FormDigest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formdigest.aspx) control and see if that will do what you need.